# Why does Quidditch Through the Ages not discuss the Snitch's flesh memory enchantment?

Tags: harry-potter

From Chapter Seven of *Deathly Hallows*:

> "Because Snitches have flesh memories," she said.
>
> "What?" said Harry and Ron together; both considered Hermione's Quidditch knowledge negligible.
>
> "Correct," said Scrimgeour. "A Snitch is not touched by bare skin before it is released, not even by the maker, who wears gloves. It carries an enchantment by which it can identify the first human to lay hands upon it, in case of a disputed capture."

This would seem to be an important fact about Quidditch, and as such I would expect it to be mentioned in the authoritative book on Quidditch — *Quidditch Through the Ages* by Kennilworthy Whisp. Yet it does not appear to be mentioned there. Other enchantments on the Snitch *are* mentioned. For instance:

> Unlike the Snidget, however, the Snitch had been bewitched to remain within the boundaries of the field.

And:

> It is bewitched to evade capture as long as possible.

So why does the very pertinent fact about their flesh memory enchantments not appear in *Quidditch Through the Ages*?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a minor retcon. Quidditch Throughout the Ages was published in 2001, Goblet of Fire in 2000, and Order of the Phoenix in 2003. Deathly Hallows, which was where the detail was mentioned, was published in 2007, six years and three whole books since Quidditch Throughout the Ages.